# Can I make a copy of my Facebook fan page without copy-pasting posts?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a json file from graph.facebook.com with all the posts we made at https://facebook.com/greenpeace.international from Nov 1 to Dec 31, and for a research project I need to recreate the page on Facebook without likes and comments -- just the posts which we made, in the same order.

We post messages, photos, videos and links. Posting messages seems simple enough to do, but I can't figure out how to deal with the photos (should I download them, and then upload?), and when I try to post links, they are posted as "Recent Posts by Others...", not as the page itself (though I have used the page_token).

Advice for PHP, Javascript or Python or just plain curl would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the *correct* page token